# Iterate in a dataframe with same values in rows

Tags: r

In a dataframe like this:

```
dfin<- data.frame(file_name = c("file1","file1","file2","file2","file2","file3","file3"), data = c(0,2,3,2,1,4,5), stock = c(3,NA,32,NA,12,3,4))
```

How is it possible to iterate in this dataframe and using the file_name column keep in every iteration the rows of the file_name which have the same value in the rows of file_name column and in the next iteration keep the next one.

From the example dataframe it will need to run the iteration 3 times and in every iteration here the results:

iteration1:

```
df<- data.frame(file_name = c("file1","file1"), data = c(0,2), stock = c(3,NA))
```

iteration2:

```
df<- data.frame(file_name = c("file2","file2","file2"), data = c(3,2,1), stock = c(32,NA,12))
```

iteration3:

```
df<- data.frame(file_name = c("file3","file3"), data = c(4,5), stock = c(3,4))
```

In a dataframe like this:

```
dfin<- data.frame(file_name = c("file1","file1","file2","file2","file2","file3","file3"), data = c(0,2,3,2,1,4,5), stock = c(3,NA,32,NA,12,3,4))
```

How is it possible to iterate in this dataframe and using the file_name column keep in every iteration the rows of the file_name which have the same value in the rows of file_name column and in the next iteration keep the next one.

Comment: try `dfin |> tidyr::nest(data = everything(), .by = file_name)`

Comment: `split(dfin, dfin$file_name)` returns a `list` of each of your iterations

Comment: EleniKalaitzi, if the comments above and the dupe-link does not give you what you need, please [edit] your question, show how you used the code, and what's not right about the results. After that, @-ping me and we'll work through the issue, reopening the question if needed. Good luck!